# SQL Server Cursors to generate XML from a script

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, cursor

I need to use cursors to generate XML from a sql script. Basically I need the `<Table><tr><td></td></tr></Table>`! I am not sure how to get started because the cursor topic sounds so confusing to me.

```
DECLARE 

 @CustomerID int = 8,
 @UtilityCompanyID int = 1

SELECT MD.SERV_ACCT, 
       AD.ACCOUNT,
       AD.SERV_ADDRESS, 
       MAXINVDATE,
       AD.SERV_ACCT + ', ' + AD.ACCOUNT + ', ' + AD.SERV_ADDRESS AS ADB
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT SERV_ACCT, MAX(INV_DATE) as MAXINVDATE
FROM tblAPSData

WHERE SERV_ACCT NOT IN (SELECT ServiceAccount
            FROM tblMEP_Meters
            JOIN tblMEP_Sites
            ON tblMEP_Meters.SiteID = tblMEP_Sites.ID

            JOIN tblMEP_Projects
            ON tblMEP_Projects.ID = tblMEP_Sites.ProjectID

            WHERE CustomerID = 8
            AND Type = 1
            )

AND ACCOUNT IN (SELECT AccountNumber
                FROM tblMEP_CustomerAccounts
                WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID
                AND UtilityCompanyID = @UtilityCompanyID)

AND INV_DATE > DATEADD(month, -6, getdate())
GROUP BY SERV_ACCT) MD
join tblAPSdata AD 
on MD.SERV_ACCT = AD.SERV_ACCT 
and MD.MAXINVDATE = AD.INV_DATE
```

The result I want in XML to be something like that

```
SERV_ACCT   ACCOUNT         SERV_ADDRESS     ADB
0289S61288  117512280   4324E MONT          0289S61288, 117512280, 4324E MONT 
1435S01282  117512280   432E SE             1435S01282, 117512280, 432E SE  
2498S21288  117512280   reN 64 ST           2498S21288, 117512280, reN 64 ST                
5538S21284  117512280   reE DOV             5538S21284, 117512280, reE DOV
```

Comment: That's **not** XML .... what should your **XML** look like? Also: which **version** of SQL Server are you using? 2000? 2005? 2008? 2012?

Comment: I am using 2008, yes Sir, I know that is not XML but I just wanted to show you the output. I want that to be in XML using cursors.

Comment: And why would you think you need cursors? That's almost never true.

Comment: You are right! But what can I do to my supervisor? (My supervisor and I are not programmers). Would you please do it in Cursors, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your have a table `ServerAcct` that holds that data you're showing, I'd recommend using `FOR XML PATH` (and ***definitely NOT*** a cursor!) to produce the XML output.

A query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ServerAcct
FOR XML PATH('ServerAccount'),ROOT('AllAccounts')
```

will yield this output:

```
<AllAccounts>
  <ServerAccount>
    <Serv_Acct>0289S61288</Serv_Acct>
    <Account>117512280</Account>
    <Serv_Address>4324E MONT</Serv_Address>
    <ADB>0289S61288, 117512280, 4324E MONT</ADB>
  </ServerAccount>
  <ServerAccount>
    <Serv_Acct>1435S01282</Serv_Acct>
    <Account>117512280</Account>
    <Serv_Address>432E SE</Serv_Address>
    <ADB>1435S01282, 117512280, 432E SE</ADB>
  </ServerAccount>
  <ServerAccount>
    <Serv_Acct>2498S21288</Serv_Acct>
    <Account>117512280</Account>
    <Serv_Address>reN 64 ST </Serv_Address>
    <ADB>2498S21288, 117512280, reN 64 ST</ADB>
  </ServerAccount>
  <ServerAccount>
    <Serv_Acct>5538S21284</Serv_Acct>
    <Account>117512280</Account>
    <Serv_Address>reE DOV</Serv_Address>
    <ADB>5538S21284, 117512280, reE DOV</ADB>
  </ServerAccount>
</AllAccounts>
```

See the [relevant MSDN SQL Server Books Online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx) for more details on `FOR XML PATH` and how to use it - it's very flexible and highly customizable - you can do just about anything with `FOR XML PATH`!

So what exactly is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need cursors to create XML, there is a [`FOR XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) command that converts query results to XML, try it. There are lots of different options, I am sure you can get desired XML.

Here is simplest example, with `FOR XML AUTO`:

```
DECLARE 
 @CustomerID int = 8,
 @UtilityCompanyID int = 1

WITH YourQuery AS 
(
    SELECT MD.SERV_ACCT, 
           AD.ACCOUNT,
           AD.SERV_ADDRESS, 
           MAXINVDATE,
           AD.SERV_ACCT + ', ' + AD.ACCOUNT + ', ' + AD.SERV_ADDRESS AS ADB
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT SERV_ACCT, MAX(INV_DATE) as MAXINVDATE
          FROM tblAPSData

    WHERE SERV_ACCT NOT IN (SELECT ServiceAccount
            FROM tblMEP_Meters
            JOIN tblMEP_Sites
            ON tblMEP_Meters.SiteID = tblMEP_Sites.ID

            JOIN tblMEP_Projects
            ON tblMEP_Projects.ID = tblMEP_Sites.ProjectID

            WHERE CustomerID = 8
            AND Type = 1
            )

    AND ACCOUNT IN (SELECT AccountNumber
                FROM tblMEP_CustomerAccounts
                WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID
                AND UtilityCompanyID = @UtilityCompanyID)

    AND INV_DATE > DATEADD(month, -6, getdate())
    GROUP BY SERV_ACCT) MD
    join tblAPSdata AD 
    on MD.SERV_ACCT = AD.SERV_ACCT 
    and MD.MAXINVDATE = AD.INV_DATE
)
SELECT * FROM YourQuery FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

**[Simplified DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79581/1)**

*EDIT:*

If you want each row as a separate XML something like this can be done (I am not repeating the whole query from above, just last part):

```
WITH YourQuery AS 
(
  ....
)
SELECT  
(
  SELECT 
        qXml.*
    FROM YourQuery qXml
    WHERE qXml.SERV_ACCT = q.SERV_ACCT --asuming this is your PK
    FOR XML PATH ('')
)
from YourQuery q
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79581/2)**

Comment: Hi Nenad, there is a minor error in the above code, it does not show the result as a table, it is like everything next to each other in one row.

Comment: @MMMSSS Well it's an XML :) When formatted (click in SSMS) it opens as one big XMl. If you really need result like table - check the edited answer.